# Adding x,y coordinates from table in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, coordinates, csv, table

This might be quite basic, but I'm struggling with adding points to a map from a CSV table of x,y coordinates in Google Earth Engine (I have over 2000 points).

I have managed to add the points as a shapefile made with QGIS, but it would be useful to know how to upload the points from a table directly.

Here is an excerpt from the "Species.csv" with coordinates (uploaded to my personal folder):

```
x,y
-179.7568,71.17604
-179.7104,70.95287
-179.6973,71.14408
-179.62078,70.93628
-179.43982,71.17056
-179,66.75
-173.16,64.41
-172.91,64.5
-172.187278,65.875167
-172.049306,65.785611
-171.979917,65.782306
-170.58391,63.65034
-166.783333,68.35
-166.36,65.26
-166.190167,64.982833
(...)
```

Any suggestions on how to import these points and add them as a layer to the map?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the Assets tab of the Code Editor, click the “New” button, and choose “CSV file.”
2. Select your CSV file.
3. In the “Advanced options” section, change the “X column” to be “x” instead of the default “longitude”, and the “Y column” to “y”.
4. Click Upload and wait for the task to finish.

I presume you found most of these steps but might not have seen the column name options. (You could also change the column headings in your CSV file to be “longitude” and “latitude” instead of “x” and “y”.)

[image: Upload dialog]

[image: Imported map]