# Adding a CSV with GPS coordinates points to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, point, coordinates, csv, table

I'm trying to add a CSV with Lat/Lon to Google Earth Engine.

I looked at the answer below, however, I seem to be making an error somewhere.

[Adding x,y coordinates from table in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357158/adding-x-y-coordinates-from-table-in-google-earth-engine/357164#357164)

My CSV is structured as follows and is saved as comma-separated UTF-8. The file has 7000 lines, I have added the first 10:

```
y,x
50.1275,26.4817
50.1275,26.4816
40.5549,21.3141
40.5548,21.3141
46.5152,24.5436
39.0794,21.7808
39.0792,21.7808
39.0794,21.781
39.0789,21.782
39.0793,21.7811
39.0793,21.7812
```

Here are the steps I took:

1. Add new -> CSV - > Select the CSV file

[image]

2. Change X column to x and Y column to y. Dont touch anything else.

[image]

3. Wait for file to upload, ingest.

I keep getting the following when the file is uploaded (rather than the actual plotted coordinates)

> The table may not have valid geometries

Either this:
[image]

or a variation showing x and y as their own "float" columns

I've added this correctly before, but cant figure out where I am making the mistake. This is a previous "successful" upload:
[image]

Here's a link to the CSV:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GUsBqRURp6YVycyCAby3JdvzzJ0d-gsl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you upload the CSV, make sure to scroll down in the “Advanced options” section and enter the names of your coordinate columns here:

[image: (Screenshot of "X column" and "Y column")]

Answer (score 1):

Let me just say that I was having the same issue and then I just uploaded and downloaded the file using Google Drive and it worked. It seems to me to be an encoding problem that is worth to be reported.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the Excel file as CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) @KevinReid’s answer does not work, whereas if you save as CSV (Comma delimited) it does.  That solved the problem for me.