# Importing CSV table with coordinates to Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, coordinates, csv, import, table

Exactly the same problem as this: [Adding a CSV with GPS coordinates points to Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378399/adding-a-csv-with-gps-coordinates-points-to-google-earth-engine/378400#comment618665_378400)
I have tried the solution to redownload the .csv file as mentioned here but that did not work.

I have a .csv file (comma delimited, UTF-8) with containing coordinates as x and y columns: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yn4pG3DLJeKnqtfscxWdBNKWQ0faHm_O/view?usp=sharing

To upload the .csv file as an asset I use the following settings in the dialog:
[image]
[image]

So I'm only changing the x and y column names.

For some reason the coordinates are not recognized and the x and y columns are displayed as floats:

> The table may not have valid geometries

[image]

I've tried just about everything (changing csv delimiter, changing column names to latitude/longitude, add a property column etc...) can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue! If you save the excel file as CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited) it does not work, whereas if you save as CSV (Comma delimited) it does

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple script that generates the Javascript definition of the GEE points starting from a csv file:

https://github.com/lucamarini22/csv_to_gee_points

In particular, given a csv with at least 2 columns containing respectively the latitude and longitude coords, the scripts generates the definition of all the points that can be then inserted in the Code Editor of Google Earth Engine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).